# NDSolve differential-difference equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am seeking advice on how to numerically solve the following differential-difference equation:

```
sol = NDSolve[{t x'[t] + x[t]/2 + x[t - 1]/2 == 0, 
   x[t /; 0 < t <= 1] == 1/Sqrt[t]}, x, {t, 0, 20}]
```

The initial condition, which must avoid the singularity at t=0, is perhaps causing the trouble.  Or maybe I am missing something else.  If this approach is doomed to failure, then I would appreciate learning about a method that might succeed.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Any help?: `NDSolveValue[{1/2 x[-1 + t] + x[t]/2 + t Derivative[1][x][t] == 0, x[t /; t <= 1 + 1*^-12] == 1/Sqrt[t]}, x, {t, 1, 20}(*, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"*)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a complete numerical solution by splitting t range into parts 0-1, 1-2 and >2.

For 0<t<1 function has to be 1/Sqrt[t], For 1<t<2 start with variable a as xvalue at t==2 and Findroot a to satisfy x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dsuz.jpg)==1. (You can ignore the error at exacly x==1). You can also use ShootingMethod.

```
pl0 = Plot[1/Sqrt[t], {t, 0, 1}];

xsol[a_?NumericQ] := 
 x /. Flatten@
   NDSolve[{t x'[t] + x[t]/2 + 1/Sqrt[t - 1]/2 == 0, x[2] == a}, 
    x, {t, 1, 2}]

fr = FindRoot[xsol[a][1] == 1, {a, .1}] // Quiet

(* {a -> 0.0838806}  *)
```

Use Piecewise for part x[t-1] with the already known function xsol for 1<t<2

```
    xsol2 = x /. 
   Flatten@NDSolve[{t x'[t] + x[t]/2 + 
        Piecewise[{{1/2 xsol[a /. fr][t - 1], 2 < t <= 3}}, 
         x[t - 1]/2] == 0, x[2] == a /. fr}, x, {t, 2, 4}] // Quiet
```

Compare with the analytical result found by @MichaelE2

```
xo[t_] = (1 - ArcTanh[Sqrt[(-1 + t)/t]])/Sqrt[t];

xME = x /. 
  Flatten@NDSolve[{t x'[t] + x[t]/2 + x[t - 1]/2 == 0, 
 x[t /; t <= 2] == xo[t]}, x, {t, 2, 4}]

pl1a = Plot[xo[t], {t, 1, 2}, 
         PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.3], Thickness[.02], Red}]

pl1 = Plot[Evaluate[xsol[a /. fr][t]], {t, 1, 2}, 
        PlotStyle -> Black] // Quiet;

pl2 = Plot[xsol2[t], {t, 2, 4}]

pl2a = Plot[xME[t], {t, 2, 4}, 
        PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.3], Thickness[.02], Red}]

Show[pl0, pl1, pl1a, pl2, pl2a, PlotRange -> All, 
   GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

You can of course generate a piecewise function of this.

Comment: I wish to acknowledge @Akku14 in an upcoming paper: please email me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from nudging the initial condition slightly off of the singularity with the initial history `x[t /; t <= 1 + 1*^-12] == 1/Sqrt[t]`, `DSolve` can solve the problem symbolically, sort of — at least far enough to give `NDSolve` an initial condition away from the singularity.  (The time it takes `DSolve` to finish grows really fast with the length of the interval, but up to `t == 2` is quick.)

```
xf0 = DSolveValue[{t x'[t] + x[t]/2 + x[t - 1]/2 == 0, 
   x[t /; t <= 1] == 1/Sqrt[t]}, x[t], {t, 1, 2}]
xf0 = FullSimplify[FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[xf0]], t > 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
xsol = NDSolveValue[{t x'[t] + x[t]/2 + x[t - 1]/2 == 0, 
   x[t /; t <= 2] == xf0}, x, {t, 0, 4}];
Plot[xsol[t], Evaluate@Flatten@{t, xsol@"Domain"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I wish to acknowledge @MichaelE2 in an upcoming paper: please email me.  Thank you.

Comment: @S.Finch Thanks! I just sent you an email, I think. At least, it hasn't bounced yet. :)

Comment: I also wish to acknowledge @Akku14 in an upcoming paper: please email me. Thank you.

Comment: @S.Finch You probably want to put your last comment under Akku14's answer.  They won't get notified of your comment (I believe), even with the @ sign, because they haven't left a comment under this answer.